# Is there a way to prevent crash report uploads monopolizing network connection?

Tags: apport, whoopsie

I have experienced a few crashes on 14.04 and have selected the option to send crash report. Once the upload starts, my browser and mail client fail to connect to the network until crash upload completes. It seems the uploads monopolize the connection. As upload speeds are relatively low, I can experience several minutes with no browser/mail access. Is there maybe some way to lower priority of upload so concurrent network access is possible?

Comment: To stop crash report uploads or to lower the speed? The title and body are different.